# Replace Pandas NaN with Data from Different DF Based on Multiple Conditions

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, nan, fillna

I have a datafrmae "dfnan" that has NaN values and I need to replace those values with data from a different dataframe "dffill" with specific row insert position requirements by "name" and "month". My data looks like this for dfnan:

```
index   result  result  result  result  result  month   name    year
1       4       4       4       4       4       1       Bears   2022
2      20      20      20      20      20       2       Bears   2022
3       8       8       8       8       8       3       Bears   2022
4       5       5       5       5       5       4       Bears   2022
5       3       3       3       3       3       5       Bears   2022
6      19      19      19      19      19       6       Bears   2022
7      nan     nan     nan     nan     nan      7       Bears   2022
8      nan     nan     nan     nan     nan      8       Bears   2022
9      nan     nan     nan     nan     nan      9       Bears   2022
10     nan     nan     nan     nan     nan     10       Bears   2022
11     nan     nan     nan     nan     nan     11       Bears   2022
12     nan     nan     nan     nan     nan     12       Bears   2022
13      5       5       5       5       5       1       Eagles  2022
14      9       9       9       9       9       2       Eagles  2022
15     12      12      12      12      12       3       Eagles  2022
16     21      21      21      21      21       4       Eagles  2022
17      2       2       2       2       2       5       Eagles  2022
18     17      17      17      17      17       6       Eagles  2022
19    nan     nan     nan     nan      nan      7       Eagles  2022
20    nan     nan     nan     nan      nan      8       Eagles  2022
21    nan     nan     nan     nan      nan      9       Eagles  2022
22    nan     nan     nan     nan      nan     10       Eagles  2022
23    nan     nan     nan     nan      nan     11       Eagles  2022
24    nan     nan     nan     nan      nan     12       Eagles  2022
```

The data i need to fill the NaN values with is here in "dffill":

```
index   month   name    1   2   3   4   5
1       7       Bears   10  25  14  4   22
2       8       Bears   5   8   6   24  18
3       9       Bears   18  8   8   14  16
4      10       Bears   19  11  13  8   9
5      11       Bears   16  25  3   9   6
6      12       Bears   17  11  18  3   24
7       7       Eagles  15  24  11  2   25
8       8       Eagles  1   7   18  9   17
9       9       Eagles  11  11  8   18  20
10     10       Eagles  16  20  3   24  2
11     11       Eagles  10  24  6   4   19
12     12       Eagles  8   16  12  19  22
```

I am sorry but I cannot understand how to insert this row data in the correct position given the requirements of same "name" and "month".  Thank you for your help and here is the final result.

```
index   result  result  result  result  result  month   name    year
1       4       4       4       4       4       1       Bears   2022
2      20      20      20      20      20       2       Bears   2022
3       8       8       8       8       8       3       Bears   2022
4       5       5       5       5       5       4       Bears   2022
5       3       3       3       3       3       5       Bears   2022
6      19      19      19      19      19       6       Bears   2022
7      10      25      14       4      22       7       Bears   2022
8       5       8       6      24      18       8       Bears   2022
9      18       8       8      14      16       9       Bears   2022
10     19      11      13       8       9      10       Bears   2022
11     16      25       3       9       6      11       Bears   2022
12     17      11      18       3      24      12       Bears   2022
13      5       5       5       5       5       1       Eagles  2022
14      9       9       9       9       9       2       Eagles  2022
15     12      12      12      12      12       3       Eagles  2022
16     21      21      21      21      21       4       Eagles  2022
17      2       2       2       2       2       5       Eagles  2022
18     17      17      17      17      17       6       Eagles  2022
19     15      24      11       2      25       7       Eagles  2022
20      1       7      18       9      17       8       Eagles  2022
21     11      11       8      18      20       9       Eagles  2022
22     16      20       3      24       2      10       Eagles  2022
23     10      24       6       4      19      11       Eagles  2022
24      8      16      12      19      22      12       Eagles  2022
```

Comment: refer to guidelines here on providing a reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example     post data as text, preferably as a dictionary to easily reproduce the scenario

Comment: I have reformatted the text now.

Comment: Would it be possible to `dropna` on the first df, `concatenate` with the 2nd, and then `sort_values(by=['name','years','month'])`?

Comment: yes, i like your solution and i've posted a question as to how to concat both dfs after I"ve dropped the nan values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is one way to do it, which is to make use of df.update
assuming its ok to set the index and rename the df2 columns

```
#set the index on both the DF
df.set_index(['name','month'], inplace=True)
df2.set_index(['name','month'], inplace=True)

#match the columns names b/w df and df2, by taking df columns to rename df2
df2.columns=['result.' + str(int(col)-1) if str(col).isdigit()  else col for col in df2.columns]
df2.rename(columns={'result.0':'result'}, inplace=True)


#use update to update the values
df.update(df2, overwrite=False)

#reset the index, in needed
df.reset_index()
```

```
    name    month   index   result  result.1    result.2    result.3    result.4    year
0   Bears       1       1   4.0     4.0     4.0     4.0     4.0     2022
1   Bears       2       2   20.0    20.0    20.0    20.0    20.0    2022
2   Bears       3       3   8.0     8.0     8.0     8.0     8.0     2022
3   Bears       4       4   5.0     5.0     5.0     5.0     5.0     2022
4   Bears       5       5   3.0     3.0     3.0     3.0     3.0     2022
5   Bears       6       6   19.0    19.0    19.0    19.0    19.0    2022
6   Bears       7       7   10.0    25.0    14.0    4.0     22.0    2022
7   Bears       8       8   5.0     8.0     6.0     24.0    18.0    2022
8   Bears       9       9   18.0    8.0     8.0     14.0    16.0    2022
9   Bears       10      10  19.0    11.0    13.0    8.0     9.0     2022
10  Bears       11      11  16.0    25.0    3.0     9.0     6.0     2022
11  Bears       12      12  17.0    11.0    18.0    3.0     24.0    2022
12  Eagles      1       13  5.0     5.0     5.0     5.0     5.0     2022
13  Eagles      2       14  9.0     9.0     9.0     9.0     9.0     2022
14  Eagles      3       15  12.0    12.0    12.0    12.0    12.0    2022
15  Eagles      4       16  21.0    21.0    21.0    21.0    21.0    2022
16  Eagles      5       17  2.0     2.0     2.0     2.0     2.0     2022
17  Eagles      6       18  17.0    17.0    17.0    17.0    17.0    2022
18  Eagles      7       19  15.0    24.0    11.0    2.0     25.0    2022
19  Eagles      8       20  1.0     7.0     18.0    9.0     17.0    2022
20  Eagles      9       21  11.0    11.0    8.0     18.0    20.0    2022
21  Eagles      10      22  16.0    20.0    3.0     24.0    2.0     2022
22  Eagles      11      23  10.0    24.0    6.0     4.0     19.0    2022
23  Eagles      12      24  8.0     16.0    12.0    19.0    22.0    2022
```

Comment: for some reason, this solution does not translate to my larger dataset. I'm getting an error "Shape of passed values is...., indices imply ...."

Comment: I’m using df column values in renaming the df2. There seems to be a different count of column count in these two df. If you have the columns names that you want updated in df similar  in both the DF then there isn’t a need of line 3 in this solution.

Comment: @user2100039, i updated the solution to address the issue. try and advise if it works for you now.

Comment: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isdigit' this is the error now.

Comment: try with this. str(col).isdigit()  . I applied the solution on the provided dataset, which don't seem to be representative of the actual data, and there are some gaps